# Initializing a generic field (numeric) from a generic List (numeric)

Tags: dart

My class

```
class MyType<E extends num> {
  final E data;
  MyType(this.data);
  MyType.fromList(List<E> list)
      : data = list.asMap().containsKey(0) ? list[0] : 0 as E;
}
...
 final o1 = MyType<double>.fromList([]);
```

Why I am getting this error

> Unhandled exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' in
> type cast

How do I initialize a numeric field when the type is restricted as E extends num

Your detailed answer is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there are a more correct (and/or pretty) way of doing this but since `num` is restricted to only have `int` and `double` as nested types, we can add check of the type to determine which value we use:

```dart
class MyType<E extends num> {
  final E data;

  MyType(this.data);
  MyType.fromList(List<E> list)
      : data =
            list.asMap().containsKey(0) ? list[0] : ((E == int) ? 0 : 0.0) as E;
}

void main() {
  final o1 = MyType<int>.fromList([]);
  print(o1.data); // 0

  final o2 = MyType<double>.fromList([]);
  print(o2.data); // 0.0

  final o3 = MyType<num>.fromList([]);
  print(o3.data); // 0.0
}
```

Could be cleaned up by moving this logic to its own method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and I really appreciate your detailed explanation.